# $Path in bashrc on Debian

Tags: debian, vps

OS: DEBIAN 8 VPS

So I place `mips-gcc comiler` in etc folder, connect to vps throught ssh with root account, add to .bashrc this export:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/mips/bin
```

In bin folder there mips-gcc binary file. When i try to run it by mips-gcc I got error:

> bashrc can not find mips-gcc in $PATH

How to fix it?

When I try to run it from bin folder with ./mips-gcc I got the same error. On my local Debian OS all works well without any errors.

Comment: Could you please show us the output of the following commands? `file /etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc && echo $PATH`

Comment: Sure: `/etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/etc/xcompile/armv4l/bin:/etc/xcompile/armv6l/bin:/etc/xcompile/i586/bin:/etc/xcompile/m68k/bin:/etc/xcompile/mips/bin:/etc/xcompile/mipsel/bin:/etc/xcompile/powerpc/bin:/etc/xcompile/powerpc-440fp/bin:/etc/xcompile/sh4/bin:/etc/xcompile/sparc/bin:/etc/xcompile/armv5l/bin:/etc/xcompile/i686/bin:/usr/local/go/bin`

Comment: Thanks. Okay, could you also show the output of these commands? `which mips-gcc && mips-gcc`

Comment: Here: `/etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc
can't find mips-gcc in $PATH`

Comment: So to sum up, (1) `/etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc` is an executable, (2) `/et‌​c/xcompile/mips/bin` is in the `PATH`, (3) `/etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc` is found by `which` when searching for `mips-gcc`, but the shell doesn't find anything when you try to execute `mips-gcc` without an absolute path. Very interesting, since up to know I thought this would be impossible! Looking forward to the solution.

Comment: I thought that it's impossible too. But as you see it's possible! So i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Btw, if i enter full path with bin file name like /etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc i got the same result - cant' find mips-gcc in $PATH

Comment: Can you try running the `/etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc` command in a clean shell? (e.g. `env -i bash --noprofile --norc`)

Comment: Here: `bash-4.3# /etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc
Segmentation fault
bash-4.3#`

Comment: Oh, now we're getting somewhere. Are you running this on mips platform? Other than that, is anything useful coming up if you run this through gdb? (`gdb -ex run -args /etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc`)

Comment: I'm runnig this on Debian VPS (KVM virtualization). The command with gdb return this: `bash: gdb: command not found`

Comment: What platform is the system? (`uname -m`) Also, you need to install `gdb`. Run `apt-get install gdb` as user `root`.

Comment: The uname -m is `uname -m x86_64`

Comment: Here is an output of gdb: `Starting program: /etc/xcompile/mips/bin/mips-gcc

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048266 in ?? ()
(gdb)`

Comment: Oh, it seems like you've downloaded the 32bit version. You need a 64bit version of `mips-gcc`!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the analysis in the comments, the `mips-gcc` binary is an `ELF 32-bit LSB executable` according to `file`, while your system is `x86_64` according to `uname -m`. That won't work. You need to use the proper binary for the system platform.

Download the 64bit version of the `gcc` for `mips`. If your Debian flavor is `jessie`, do the following as user `root`:

```
1. echo "deb http://www.emdebian.org/tools/debian/ jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/embedian.list
2. apt-get update
3. apt-get install emdebian-archive-keyring
4. apt-get install gcc-mips-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Gonna try to use Debian x86 version of OS. Thanks for your answear!

Comment: @Sirius glad I could help!

Comment: So i had reinstall OS to the Debian 7x86, `uname -m i686`, install from the same link mips-gcc, and have the same error. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Sirius Weird. The binary must be broken in some other way then? Why don't you install the mips `gcc` from the Emdebian archive?

Comment: Your commands for jessie Debian, i'm using Debian 7 wheezy. So the commands different for me? Btw, if i enter `mips-gcc` without `env -i bash --noprofile --norc` i have the same error `not found in $PATH`. Localy everything works well. Maby the problem in KVM virtualization or cause i'm doing all this trought ssh?

Comment: Where did you get that binary `mips-gcc` from in the first place? Also, instructions for `wheezy` should be pretty similar to those for `jessie`.

Comment: From here `https://www.uclibc.org/downloads/binaries/0.9.30.1/cross-compiler-mips.tar.bz2`

Comment: The binaries from this link execute without problems on a `x86_64` Debian `jessie`. Since they don't seem to depend on any external libs, you can execute them even without installing 32bit libc etc. They should work on `wheezy`, too, since multiarch support should work out of the box in `wheezy`.

Comment: Yes, its work without any problems on my local Debian 8. But on VPS i have problems with it.